# SQL Connection Pool timeout setting and SQL Server remote query setting

Tags: asp.net, sql, timeout, connection-string

ASP.Net ConnectionStrings have persistent pooling on by default, and SQL Server default has a 600 second Remote query timeout. I assume that for a pooling at works each pooling connection would stay open for a long time.

Does the 600 second default setting affect the use of connection pooling?  Such that a random connection timeout error would occur from time to time? or it works with pool seamlessly. Should I change max remote query timeout to 0 (infinite) instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the timeout affects pooling. If you have long running database queries that stay open for 600 seconds, and new requests are comming in, changes are that the connection pool is running out of connections.

Comment: when connection time out happen? if front end UI trying to connect sql server for long time then connection time out happen? or for a long time any connection open from UI but not close & staying idle then also connection time out happen? please guide.